# How to combine two rows into one based on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example:

```
Column A   Column B   Column C
   A_1        B_1       0
   A_1        B_1       1
   A_1        B_2       2
   A_1        B_2       3
```

I would like to get:

```
Column A   Column B   Column C
   A_1        B_1       1
   A_1        B_2       5
```

I tried doing `df.groupby(["Column A", "Column B"])["Column C"].sum()` but I am returned with a Series object where the indices are based on `(Column A, Column B)` with a column `Column C` and the numbers were concatenated rather than sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `df.groupby`, specify `as_index=False` so that the columns aren't converted to an `Index`. You can use `df.agg` after a groupby.

```
In [990]: df.groupby(["Column A", "Column B"], as_index=False).agg('sum')
Out[990]: 
  Column A Column B  Column C
0      A_1      B_1         1
1      A_1      B_2         5
```

Comment: Thanks! I did a mistake when I read my data file. Column C should be changed to numeric type first. That's why I have been getting string concatenation rather than sum for both your code and mine. I realized using `.sum()` gives the exact same answer too.

Comment: @StanleyGan If you prefer a MultiIndex, your solution is fine. Otherwise, I recommend this one. Cheers.